# Xampp server Unable to Connect to ssl:// at port 443

Tags: ssl, xampp

i was recentyly testing google spreadsheet api using Zend Framework, but Got this error

```
Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message 'Unable to Connect to ssl://www.google.com:443. Error #148105208: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?' in ....
```

I am using Xampp 1.7.4 , i have checked httpd.conf, mod_ssl.so is enabled there. please help

Comment: Possibly dumb question, but are you sure you use `ssl://www.google.com:443` rather than just `https://www.google.com`?

Comment: This was the unmodified part of the error i get from zend framework . i think https works using ssl protocol,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message appears to be related to the php ssl module, not apache. You can check what modules are enabled by running `php -m`. Look for an openssl line.

If it is not enabled you can enable it in your php.ini file by adding the line:

`extension=php_openssl.so`

The above applies to linux, on windows you would use:

`extension=php_openssl.dll`

It may be that this line is commented out in your XAMPP installation.